# Rename search service databases after creting search service app with central admin

Tags: 2016, enterprise-search

Hi I crated Search service application  in sharepoint 2016 with central admin if any good way to rename the databases all search components deployed to one application server.

Comment: I'm unsure if you can rename a database after it has been created. I think you'll have to provision the search service using PowerShell to be able to choose the related databases name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename them but you can restore your Search Service Application from backup and at that time rename the Admin DB. The other databases will be recreated using the Admin DB name as the root. Check out the Restore-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication cmdlet.